# Add Checkbox in doc report using python-docx

Tags: python-3.x, report, python-docx, odoo-12

I want to generate doc report using python with checkbox functionality. I am  able to generate report using python-docx but I need to add checkbox for various options.

Thanks,

Comment: what are you tried? Please show some piece of your code.

Comment: I followed this but it was just printing string not checkbox. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46524872/how-can-i-insert-a-checkbox-form-into-a-docx-file-using-python-docx