# python3.5 : How to add checkbox using python-docx library?

Tags: xml, python-3.x

I wonder how to add checkbox or at least something that is square (I mean, I don't need to check or uncheck it).
I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46524872/how-can-i-insert-a-checkbox-form-into-a-docx-file-using-python-docx) but it doesn't work. I find [this](https://www.xmldocx.com/api-documentation/docxutilities/parsecheckboxes) but it uses XmlDocx and it needs according to me those xml (that I don't want to integrate with my Odoo module).
I find [here](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/224) how checkbox looks like in xml format

```
<w:checkBox>
 <w:sizeAuto />
 <w:default w:val="0">
 <w:checked/>
</w:checkBox>
```

But don't know how to integrate it in Document() object.
Can you help me? Thank you very much.

This is my code in main :

```
filename = '%s.docx' % self.acronym
logo = base64.b64decode(self.company_id.logo)
logo_filename = "logo.jpg"
full_path_logo = os.path.join('/tmp', logo_filename)
with open(full_path_logo, 'wb') as f:
     f.write(logo)
full_path_filename = os.path.join('/tmp', filename)
document = Document()
style = document.styles['Normal']
font = style.font
font.name = 'Arial'
```

Comment: Can you share a bit more code? What is the Document() object you referring to?

Comment: @iddos Document() is the main python-docx object()